# How to extract only date from full date (2011-05-15) and store in array in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Full date string 2011-05-15, 2011-05-17, 2011-05-18, 2011-05-20, are comes from server i want to extract only Day value (15,17,18,20..etc) and store it in ur local Array
and show these days(these are Events days) in calendar with red color. how can i do this. Please any one give me idea.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: 16th question and zero accepted... You really should review your old ones and accept answers that solved your problems

Comment: you know, in the upper right corner you'll find a searchbox. if you enter "NSDate from string", this will happen: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSDate+from+string

Answer (score 1):

The following block should help you

```
NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSString *date in [@"2011-05-15, 2011-05-17, 2011-05-18, 2011-05-20" componentsSeperatedByString:@","])
{
    NSString *day=[[date componentsSeperatedByString:@"-"] objectAtIndex:2];
    [arr addObject:day];
}
```

Comment: thanks foe replying me @Rama Krishna, suddenly my client change the webservices these are the day,month, year formate. i am storing day in mutable array and i want to show these day in current month of calendar with red color.

Comment: my calendar delegate is - (KLTile *)calendarView:(KLCalendarView *)calendarView createTileForDate:(KLDate *)date{
}

Comment: for (int i = 0; i<[dayArray count]; i++) {
        if(year)
        {
            tile.checkmarked = YES;
            tile.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
    }

Comment: And date Array value is  10,5,26,28 i want to show these date in calendar with red color